# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges for Oracle view

Tags: oracle, view, database-schema, ora-01031

We are running Oracle database 19c and we have got a strange error for `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`

There are two users/schemas, for short, I call them `mgr` and `user` here.

So on `mgr`, I have created this view:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "MGR"."EVENT" (...) AS 
  SELECT  ... FROM c_interfaces.c_event et
     LEFT JOIN event_module em ON (...)
     LEFT JOIN event_location cl ON (...)
     LEFT JOIN users u ON (...)
     WHERE ... ORDER BY ...;

  GRANT SELECT ON "MGR"."EVENT" TO "USER" WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Using `mgr`, I can `SELECT` this view without problem.

Then when I used `user` to call:

```
select * from "MGR"."EVENT";
```

I got this error:

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

I don't know what went wrong.
When I used `user` for debugging and I tried to cut out the `select` part and run:

```
  SELECT  ... FROM c_interfaces.c_event et
     LEFT JOIN event_module em ON (...)
     LEFT JOIN event_location cl ON (...)
     LEFT JOIN users u ON (...)
     WHERE ... ORDER BY ...;
```

I got no error at all. Data is displayed correctly on my screen.

So what could be wrong?

Comment: I would guess the view is invalid because mgr no longer has all the grants needed to select from all of the underlying tables.

Comment: @kfinity I have just tested, I can do `select * from event;` with `mgr` without any problem.